Can't upgrade to Kubuntu 24.04
I have Kubuntu 23.10. When I type:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && do-release-upgrade
I get:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

Changing to normal in the file above also does nothing.
What's going on?

The upgrade path is not open due to BLOCKER bugs.
For update in September 2024 - skip to near end
Refer to https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-release-status-tracking/44043 for the current status, and especially note the "Current blockers for enabling upgrades from Mantic" section for BLOCKER bugs for mantic (23.10) to noble (24.04).
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is currently available for new installs, which is the purpose of the ISO release.
The do-release-upgrade command will check what upgrades are available; which it does by reading https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release where you'll note no mention of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, as it's not currently supported for release-upgrades.
Forcing Upgrade
You can force upgrade using the -d option, which will cause this file (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development) to be used instead, thus it will be seen, but that is available mostly for QA or Quality Assurance testing, and will remain that until the BLOCKER bugs have been dealt with. The upgrade will be opened when the Ubuntu Release team deem the upgrade to be stable.
The official upgrade documentation can be read at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NobleUpgrades where you'll note -d is mentioned.
Additional notes
It's normal for a release to not be opened until the following week after release (releases are always a Thursday), and for LTS releases, that upgrade can sometimes open a week or two later too.  The LTS to LTS release is the same, except the 22.04 LTS won't be examined until after release of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
Also please note Kubuntu is the same as Ubuntu here, with all release-upgrades using the same code with upgrades for all (inc. flavors like Kubuntu) managed by the Ubuntu Release team.
Update on 24.04.1 Tracking
See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/46972 for tracking status of the 22.04.1 release, and take particular attention of the "Upgrade blockers" section.
You'll also note on that page that the planned date of 15-August-2024 has been pushed back to 29-August-2024.
Update September 2024 (Paused Upgrades)
The path of upgrades from 22.04 to 24.04 was opened after release of 24.04.1, but it was soon recognized  some users were experiencing problems and thus the 'taps" were paused (see here)
Utkarsh Gupta (of the Ubuntu Release team) has provided 'public notice' which reads

We’ve discovered a bug in ubuntu-release-upgrader in the code that enables a new apt algorithm to handle obsolete packages.
Therefore, updates to Noble have been temporarily suspended while the issue is being addressed.
The fixes are in the pipeline already and we should be re-enabling the upgrades soon. Once done, expect to hear from us along with the retrospective on what happened and what we are doing to ensure that this doesn’t happen again.

Upgrades to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS are enabled again
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/upgrades-to-ubuntu-24-04-1-lts-are-enabled-again/47920
Julian Andres Klode gives a brief summary on suspension & tells us the issue has been resolved and upgrades are back open. The reason for suspension is outlined, plus for any systems that were 'broken' by this issue, a simple apt install --fix-broken should resolve issues.

I've always secretly wondered if the delay is to test against new install failures to fix before allowing the upgrade for established systems...which could be fatal in a production env. The published blockers tend to indicate otherwise, but it might be a (sneaky) good policy.

Even with -d it doesn't currently work:
sudo do-release-upgrade -d Checking for a new Ubuntu release There is no development version of an LTS available. To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release  set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

@autarchprinceps The -d did work awhile (we used it extensively during QA).. but if it's been disabled via changes to the https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development I would not force it and be patient... as the Ubuntu Release team are still working hard on the 24.04 LTS release, with reasons for their decisions.  If lucky, you won't have to wait long too.

Yesterday, the meta-release file got updated with 24.04 LTS, but not the meta-release-lts. Because of this, I still couldn't do the upgrade from 22.04 LTS. However, when I set to upgrade to other versions as well, the updater offers me to upgrade to 23.10 instead. Is this normal? Would I need to upgrade twice?

Yes that is expected.. Check your calendar, it's not 15 August 2024 yet and Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS has not been released.. thus there is no expectation of a 22.04 to 24.04 upgrade; only 22.04 to 23.10; the upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 is open yes so you could release-upgrade twice.. or be patient & go direct when its deemed safe & ready for that.  @AdamL.S.

Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS tracker can be viewed at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/46972   (You'll also see the release date provided there; which has been pushed back too)

The upgrade was opened,. and then later closed as mentioned here (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-release/2024-September/006225.html) due to a problem in apt (in proposed last time I checked), so upgrades from 22.04 to 24.04 are currently halted (unless forced with -d) but will re-open once fix is available

Well, I tried now and the upgrade crashed saying "The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?". And before that is an cast error - unexpected float. Meh...

I found the upgrades enabled
(meta-release & meta-release-lts)
and it worked for me from 22.04 LTS (WSL).
This answer was invaluable in understanding and tracking the issue. Thank you!

See: https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-24-04-lts-noble-numbat-released/
Note: For upgrades from 23.10, there may a delay of a few hours to days between the official release announcements and the Ubuntu Release Team enabling upgrades.

that didn't work, but I already found manual way to upgrade and I'm just typing on new version: sudo sed -i 's/mantic/noble/g'  /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo reboot - it seems something was wrong in my sources.list (this laptop has Kubuntu for almost a decade)

@iirekm It wasn't supposed to "work".  It was to inform you that the distribution upgrade is not ready for installed systems as per the Kubuntu documentation.  See the note.

how about updates from 22.10?

Upgrading manually worked in my case:
sudo sed -i 's/mantic/noble/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean && sudo reboot

Something was messed up in sources.list and do-release-upgrade couldn't fix it.

This is NOT a supported way to do a release upgrade of Ubuntu.

I think this is a fine answer, excepting that it should warn that it is unsupported, and say something like "this will install the mantic packages from your sources.list, etc., but is not officially an upgrade; do this at your own risk, make sure to backup your data". I've used this technique several times for Kubuntu upgrade in the past.

If you think the updates aren't ready, you should put an appropriate message in the do-release-update, instead of blocking the updates and giving me -3 reputation! Shame on you!
BTW 24.04 is a disaster, I already found 3 bugs and posted on AskUbuntu: problems with Samsung smart monitor sound, UI glitches in jetbrains ides and vscode, problems with Electron-based apps like FreeTube or Shadow PC.
What the hell are you doing Canonical? For 2 decades I had no such issues, even with development releases of Ubuntu. Sorry, I've had it! I'm switching to another distro or Windows :-(

@iirekm So you upgraded onto an unreleased version in an non-recommended roundabout way, got a few bugs because of that, and you think that -3 rep is unwarranted and your answer should be and accepted answer? There's something wrong with your attitude, buddy.
