When will 24.04 be available for upgrade for 22.04 users
So I tried upgrading my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 and I keep getting 'updates/upgrade not found'. I don’t want to force upgrade and have issues later or crashes.
Any idea when we are getting updates?

Upgrade paths will open after 24.04.1 is released, which will take several months. Don't force upgrade. See https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/04/dont-upgrade-to-ubuntu-24-04-yet

Did you read any of the announcements of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Released, eg.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/04/25/ubuntu-24-04-lts-noble-numbat-released/

Users of Ubuntu 23.10 will soon be offered an automatic upgrade to 24.04. Users of 22.04 LTS will be offered the automatic upgrade when 24.04.1 LTS is released, which is scheduled for the 15th of August. For further information about upgrading, see:

ie. 15 August 2024 is actually mentioned (ISO release of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS); which is still in the future.
In practice release-upgrades are not on that date (15 August 2024 (all releases are scheduled for Thursday) but is usually early the following week (unless blocker bugs still exist, which will cause a further delay as per the release status page)
The status page available currently is https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-release-status-tracking/44043 with more up to date details available on launchpad.

Update on 24.04.1 Tracking
See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/46972 for tracking status of the 22.04.1 release, and take particular attention of the "Upgrade blockers" section.
You'll also note on that page that the planned date of 15-August-2024 has been pushed back to 29-August-2024.

FYI:   If you read a different announcement page (I'm using that one as its ultra easy for me to find) the text will be the same, as details are just copy/pasted from an official text.

I just checked and it's delayed. The release of 24.04.1 will be on August 29, 2024! https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-24-04-1-point-release-delayed-until-august-29/47110

Thanks, I forgot this answer exists; I added a note on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1511602/cant-upgrade-to-kubuntu-24-04/1511642#1511642; I may copy/paste what I added to that question here
