Xubuntu headless distribution upgrade
I'm trying to update Xubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS on my headless server without success.
What I've tried:

I installed update-manager to be able to upgrade to 24.04 (as stated on the Xubuntu website) using Remmina / XRDP. However, when executing update-manager -c -d, I do get a message telling me that there's a newer version of Xubuntu, but when clicking "Update...", I'm being thrown out the application with an error message that says Error executing command as another user: Not authorized despite having typed my sudo password after application start.
When executing sudo update-manager -c -d, I'm getting a warning Gtk-WARNING: cannot open display: :10.0 and the application exits.

So I tried a pure-cli approach:

sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade
sudo vim /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and set Prompt=lts
sudo do-release-upgrade will just tell me that there's no development version of an LTS available.

What am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?
I've also posted this question on Server Fault, however without getting an answer.
Thanks in advance.

Have you read the release notes for 24.04; the upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 opened awhile ago (as stated on release; it would open soon), but the upgrade from prior LTS (ie. 22.04 to 24.04) won't open until after release of 24.04.1 which it said was scheduled on 15 August 2024; a release & date which hasn't yet been released. Upgrades currently require 22.04 -> 23.10 then 23.10 -> 24.04 as what you're after isn't yet open (as documented)

https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/04/25/ubuntu-24-04-lts-noble-numbat-released/ (or the release notes themselves as its the same text)  states I feel rather clearly "Users of Ubuntu 23.10 will soon be offered an automatic upgrade to 24.04. Users of 22.04 LTS will be offered the automatic upgrade when 24.04.1 LTS is released, which is scheduled for the 15th of August. For further information about upgrading, see:..."  or if you check Xubuntu release notes you'll find the same text (via link; same text was used on all notices)

Sorry - I marked the incorrect duplicate..  The question/answer I intended & should have picked is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1513711/when-will-24-04-be-available-for-upgrade-for-22-04-users/1513716#1513716  (the question I tagged was 23.10 to 24.04 which opened long ago now..)

@guiverc Cheers for the answer, don't know why I didn't read this.
