Unable to upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 from 22.04 "Could not calculate the upgrade"
I am upgrading through the software updater (update-manager) application after enabling "For any new version" in the software and updates application under the "Updates" tab for "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" so that I may upgrade to 24.04. It should be noted that I just completed an upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.
The upgrade stops and displays a splash that contains:
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

 This was likely caused by:
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

I used this (Could not calculate the upgrade, what happened?) page as a main source of help.
In the /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log file I only found a single error towards the end:
2024-08-06 00:48:17,907 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'

So I decided to check the /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log file by doing:
grep Broken /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log

Which gave me:
Broken coreutils:amd64 Breaks on usrmerge:amd64 < 25ubuntu2 @ii mK > (< 39)
Broken python3:amd64 Conflicts on python3-distutils:amd64 < 3.10.8-1~22.04 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 Conflicts on libtss2-mu0:amd64 < 3.2.0-1ubuntu1.1 @ii gK >
Broken wireplumber:amd64 Conflicts on pipewire-media-session:amd64 < 0.4.1-2ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken pipewire-audio:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU >
Broken pipewire-audio:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio:i386 < none | 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @un uH >
Broken pipewire-audio:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU >
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core:amd64 < 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5 -> 4:24.2.4-0ubuntu0.24.04.2 @ii umU > (= 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5)
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Depends on libreoffice-core-nogui:amd64 < none | 4:24.2.4-0ubuntu0.24.04.2 @un umH > (= 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.5)
Broken python3-uno:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.10.6-1~22.04 -> 3.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (< 3.11)
Broken libpcap0.8t64:amd64 Depends on libibverbs1:amd64 < none | 50.0-2build2 @un umH > (>= 1.1.6)
Broken nautilus:amd64 Breaks on nautilus-share:amd64 < 0.7.3-2ubuntu6 @ii umH > (< 0.7.3-2ubuntu7~)
Broken libpcre3:amd64 Breaks on libpcre3:i386 < 2:8.39-13ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii gK Ib > (!= 2:8.39-15build1)
Broken tcpdump:amd64 Depends on libpcap0.8t64:amd64 < none | 1.10.4-4.1ubuntu3 @un umH > (>= 1.9.1)
Broken vim:amd64 Depends on vim-common:amd64 < 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.17 -> 2:9.1.0016-1ubuntu7.1 @ii umU > (= 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.17)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on hplip-data:amd64 < 3.21.12+dfsg0-1 -> 3.23.12+dfsg0-0ubuntu5 @ii umU > (= 3.21.12+dfsg0-1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libhpmud0:amd64 < 3.21.12+dfsg0-1 -> 3.23.12+dfsg0-0ubuntu5 @ii umU > (= 3.21.12+dfsg0-1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on libsane-hpaio:amd64 < 3.21.12+dfsg0-1 -> 3.23.12+dfsg0-0ubuntu5 @ii umU IPb > (= 3.21.12+dfsg0-1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on printer-driver-hpcups:amd64 < 3.21.12+dfsg0-1 -> 3.23.12+dfsg0-0ubuntu5 @ii umU > (= 3.21.12+dfsg0-1)
Broken hplip:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.10.6-1~22.04 -> 3.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (< 3.11)
Broken libiw30t64:amd64 Conflicts on libiw30:amd64 < 30~pre9-13.1ubuntu4 @ii mK > (< 30~pre9-16.1ubuntu2)
Broken gnome-panel:amd64 Breaks on libgnome-panel0:amd64 < 1:3.44.0-1ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 1:3.49)
Broken libgegl-0.4-0t64:amd64 Depends on libumfpack6:amd64 < none | 1:7.6.1+dfsg-1build1 @un umH > (>= 1:7.0.1)
Broken libgimp2.0t64:amd64 Depends on libgegl-0.4-0t64:amd64 < none | 1:0.4.48-2.4build2 @un umH > (>= 1:0.4.38)
Broken libsgutils2-1.46-2:amd64 Breaks on libsgutils2-2:amd64 < 1.46-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK > (< 1.46-3ubuntu2)
Broken gimp:amd64 Depends on libgimp2.0t64:amd64 < none | 2.10.36-3ubuntu0.24.04.1 @un umH > (>= 2.10.36)
Broken fbreader:amd64 Breaks on libzlui-gtk:amd64 < 0.12.10dfsg2-6 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99)
Broken libgs-common:amd64 Breaks on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mK > (< 10)
Broken libportsmf0t64:amd64 Breaks on libportsmf0v5:amd64 < 0.1~svn20101010-5ubuntu2 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.1~svn20101010-7build1)
Broken iftop:amd64 Depends on libpcap0.8t64:amd64 < none | 1.10.4-4.1ubuntu3 @un umH > (>= 0.9.8)
Broken endeavour-common:amd64 Breaks on gnome-todo-common:amd64 < 3.28.1-6ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 42)
Broken pulseaudio-module-jack:amd64 Depends on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 | 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umR > (= 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10)
Broken libcurl3t64-gnutls:i386 Depends on libldap2:i386 < none | 2.6.7+dfsg-1~exp1ubuntu8 @un umH > (>= 2.6.2)
Broken python3-dev:amd64 Depends on python3:amd64 < 3.10.6-1~22.04 -> 3.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii umU > (= 3.10.6-1~22.04)
Broken libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 Depends on gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 -> 44.0-5build2 @ii umU > (< 43~)
Broken libgnome-desktop-4-1:amd64 Depends on gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 -> 44.0-5build2 @ii umU > (< 43~)
Broken libodbc1:amd64 Depends on libodbc2:amd64 < 2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1 -> 2.3.12-1ubuntu0.24.04.1 @ii umU > (= 2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1)
Broken libwine-development:amd64 Depends on libpcap0.8:amd64 < 1.10.1-4build1 @ii pmR > (>= 0.9.8)
Broken libpulsedsp:amd64 Depends on libpulse0:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU > (= 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2)
Broken python3-ldb:amd64 Depends on libldb2:amd64 < 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.2 -> 2:2.8.0+samba4.19.5+dfsg-4ubuntu9 @ii umU > (= 2:2.4.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.2)
Broken libgs9:amd64 Depends on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mR > (= 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9)
Broken libfwupdplugin5:amd64 Depends on libfwupd2:amd64 < 1.7.9-1~22.04.3 -> 1.9.16-1 @ii umU > (= 1.7.9-1~22.04.3)
Broken python3-talloc:amd64 Depends on libtalloc2:amd64 < 2.3.3-2build1 -> 2.4.2-1build2 @ii umU > (= 2.3.3-2build1)
Broken libgnome-bg-4-1:amd64 Depends on libgnome-desktop-4-1:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 3.17.92)
Broken idle-python3.10:amd64 Depends on python3.10-tk:amd64 < none @un mH >
Broken ppp:amd64 Depends on libpcap0.8t64:amd64 < none | 1.10.4-4.1ubuntu3 @un umH > (>= 0.9.8)
Broken network-manager-pptp:amd64 Depends on ppp:amd64 < 2.4.9-1+1ubuntu3 | 2.4.9-1+1.1ubuntu4 @ii umR > (< 2.4.9-2~)
Broken nautilus:amd64 Breaks on nautilus-share:amd64 < 0.7.3-2ubuntu6 @ii umH > (< 0.7.3-2ubuntu7~)
Broken network-manager-pptp-gnome:amd64 Depends on network-manager-pptp:amd64 < 1.2.10-1 | 1.2.12-3build2 @ii umR > (= 1.2.12-3build2)
Broken pptp-linux:amd64 Depends on ppp:amd64 < 2.4.9-1+1ubuntu3 | 2.4.9-1+1.1ubuntu4 @ii umR >
Broken libmutter-10-0:amd64 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 Depends on libmutter-10-0:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu8 @ii mR > (= 42.9-0ubuntu8)
Broken nautilus:amd64 Breaks on nautilus-share:amd64 < 0.7.3-2ubuntu6 @ii umH > (< 0.7.3-2ubuntu7~)

I have 35 broken packages according to pkgProblemResolver in this apt.log file. It is to be noted that this number was larger before. I got the number way down to 35 by removing wine and thunderbird (which I wasn't using anyways):
sudo apt-get remove wine && sudo apt-get remove thunderbird
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean

Autoremove removed some unnecessary dependencies which brought the count down.
The splash calls attention to PPAs that are not provided by Ubuntu, but this doesn't seem to be the issue for me considering main.log does not give any error pertaining to a package or PPA, but to the pkgProblemResolver. Which prompted me to look inside apt.log.
After all this, I continue to receive the same splash mentioned before. I am very hesitant to remove any more packages from the list in apt.log, as I may remove an essential package for Ubuntu to upgrade or function.
Is the answer in apt.log or main.log?
How can I find out which packages of the 35 are the root of the issue?
I have searched through many online forums but none give a conclusive fix to the issue I have. I would be very grateful if anyone could supply any sort of information or help before I make a grave mistake trying to fix this myself.

Have you tried to fix the broken packages?

You do realize that the 22.04 to 24.04 upgrade is not yet deemed stable and thus isn't open.  The date given in the release notes of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS hasn't yet been reached for that upgrades; so are there reasons why you're trying to hurry the upgrade process?  For best results I'll suggest considering till the process is deemed stable and thus upgrade is actually officially opened.

@amar I have tried sudo apt install -f and sudo dpkg --configure -a both didn't seem to improve the situation.

There is also sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..R which shows packages marked for reinstall, I would also listen to guiverc.

apt-get clean promptly erases all the work of apt-get autoclean. Use only one, not both.

"main.log does not give any error pertaining to a package or PPA" It rarely does, but PPAs and other non-Ubuntu repos are the #1 cause anyway. symptoms get logged. It's not smart enough to find and log the cause of that symptom. Determining that cause is the human's job.

@guiverc I have no rush really, just wanted to get fully updated. I saw online people had little to no issues with 24.04 now, but this could be for many reasons. I will wait until the release of 24.04.1 on Aug 15th and I will update my progress then. Thank you.

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is stable, currently for new installs, or for upgrades from 23.10 (which was a relatively small upgrade; given 23.10 & 24.04 were rather close)..  You're from a prior LTS release cycle, and your upgrade path is not yet deemed stable (*but is getting close; you can view status at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/46972 though that is really for the ISO release (ie. new installs again), with the release-upgrades from 22.04 being evaluated in the following week usually (don't expect to be offered it on that date).

If interested in the upgrade; I mention it on an answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1513711/when-will-24-04-be-available-for-upgrade-for-22-04-users/1513716#1513716 but you'll find it referenced many places anyway (the procedure hasn't changed in a long time and is consistent)
